# Command /RU system is blocking task's creation (schtasks)

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I wrote a script, which allows me to plan a task with SCHTASKS and it works, but whenever I try to execute the command with the option /RL HIGHEST, or /RU SYSTEM, the task is not even created.

Don't know why, please help me !

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Have you checked the event log?

Comment: I think `/RU System` requires user and pass for a user with admin permissions with `[/U username [/P password]]` switches.may be its the same for /rl

Answer (score 1):

Both  `/RL HIGHEST` or `/RU SYSTEM` arguments of `SCHTASKS /Create` require elevation. Otherwise, `ERROR: Access is denied` is raised.

Run your script elevated. The [Run as Administrator in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3436-run-administrator-windows-10-a.html) article shows ten ways to achieve elevation however *Option Two: To Run as Administrator using Context Menu* should suffice in most conditions:

> - Option One: To Run as Administrator using Keyboard Shortcut
> - Option Two: **To Run as Administrator using Context Menu**
> - Option Three: To Run as Administrator in Apps screen and Start screen Options
> - Option Four: To Run as Administrator in Start Menu
> - Option Five: To Run as Administrator in File Explorer Ribbon
> - Option Six: To Run as Administrator on Taskbar
> - Option Seven: To Run as Administrator in Task Manager
> - Option Eight: To Always Run as Administrator in Shortcut Advanced Properties
> - Option Nine: To Always Run as Administrator in Compatibility Properties
> - Option Ten: To Always Run as Administrator in Registry Editor